# CakePHP doesn't validate or hash my password before saving

Tags: php, cakephp

it works perfectly for my "register" action but it doesn't work for my "forgetPassword" action.

The notEmpty validation works for both but my custom validaton for matching values in password and confirm password doesn't work on my "forgetPassword" but it work on my "register" action.

Here is a snippet of validaton code from my model

```
        'confirm_password' => array(
            'confirm password field cannot be empty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left empty'
            ),

            'confirm password must match password' => array(
                'rule' => 'matchPassword',
                'message' => 'The two passwords do not match'

            )

        ),
```

and here is other methods in my model

```
    public function matchPassword($check){
        if(strcmp($this->data['User']['password'],$this->data['User']['confirm_password']) != 0){
            $this->invalidate('password','The two password do not match');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeSave($options = array()){
        if(!$this->id){
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and my forget_password.ctp

```
<h1>Enter Your New Password</h1>
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', array('type' => 'password','label' => 'Type again')); ?>          
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Change', array('class' =>'button')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

And here is the update password method I'm using in controller to update the password

```
    protected function _updatePassword($id,$password){
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $this->User->data['User']['password'] = $password;
        if($this->User->save($this->User->data,false)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Instead of doing 
`$password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];`

and then passing this $password as a argument to _updatePassword($id,$password) to use it as
`$this->User->data['User']['password'] = $password;
$this->user->save($this->User->data);`

now I am doing `$this->User->save($this->request->data);` and the validation is working. But the password hash issue is still there.

**Update 2:**

Even I removed that `if(!$this->id){` It was not working. so I used something like this in my controller

```
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->User->id = $id;
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            if(isset($this->request->data['User']['password']) and isset($this->request->data['User']['confirm_password'])){
                $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->request->data['User']['password']);
                $this->request->data['User']['confirm_password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->request->data['User']['confirm_password']);
            }
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
```

To accomplish the task.

Comment: You set `validate = false` in your all to `$this->User->save` (second parameter).

Comment: @Holt, oh I'm sorry. I didn't know that the second parameter is to disable validation. I simply picked up that pattern from Google search on serveral issues and never realized that it was for for disabling the validation. Thanks.

Edit: nah, I removed that 'false' from my second parameter but it still doesn't validate. 

BTW, what about password hasing problem?

Comment: I even changed the second parameter to true and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing the password as the second parameters of your function and then doing `$this->User->data['User']['password'] = $password;`?

Comment: @Holt Okay, the validation is working now. See my update. But the password hash issue is still there.

Comment: Use `$this->exists()` instead of `!$this->id` in your model.